# Excel - Output Values on Cells based on a predefined dictionary

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am getting data from a source but I need to change certain cells based on my "index".

Example here: [image: 1]

What is this called that I am trying to do?
Could anyone show or tell me how/where to do this?
My latest research seems to show I need to use XLOOKUP?
Please and Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether the formula is helpful.

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$10:$B$12,2,FALSE),A2)`

[image]

Any misunderstandings can let us know.